# How to not specify the type argument in a generic method when the required argument is null?

Tags: c#, generics, methods, arguments, default

I have a method:

```
public HttpRequestMessage CreateRequest<T>(T genericObject = default(T))
{
    ...
    if (!Equals(genericObject, default(T)))
    ...
}
```

I can call it:

```
var request = CreateRequest<int>();
```

Seeing as I don't actually use the default type (I would like it to set to null by default), how can I stop defining the generic type as an int(or any other type for that matter) when I call the method?

**Edit**
The point is, I usually do need to specify a type and use the argument. However sometimes I do not need to use the argument and I want it to be set to Null or Zero instead of writing a random type like 'int' in the example above

Comment: It's really not clear what you mean - the compiler needs *some* indication of what `T` should be...

Comment: `null` isn't a type. You will need to specify what you expect the method to return or write a non-generic method with some return type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not, cause *that* is a signature of your method.

You can create another method, which has no any generic arguments, so you will be able to call it like:

```
var request = CreateRequest();
```

Comment: This is the right answer! Generic methods need the object type reference always. If null it means it's not needed then you need a non Generic method.

Comment: The point is, I usually do need to specify a type and use the argument. However sometimes I do not need to use the argument and I want it to be set to Null or Zero instead of writing a random type like 'int' in the example above.

Comment: @AntonJ: it's architectural decision, so take in count how often you use it with and without parameter and add or not a method without any generic argument. It all depends on your convenience.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. For a generic function you either have to specify the generic parameter or you have to pass something that it can infer the generic parameter from.

To get around it you could write a non-generic wrapper.